# Can a captain take money from someone who died blocking or challenging it?

Tags: coup

When I steal from another player with only one card, if they challenge me and lose (or if they try to block and I challenge them and they lose), they are now out of the game.  According to a strict interpretation of the rules, they now have to return all their money to the pool and it seems like this would happen BEFORE the steal completes which means I now no longer get the money.

But when I play with friends we generally assume the captain gets the 2 coins and the rest is returned to the pool.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I checked russian rules and under "challenges" section it mentions that if an action is successful, it resolves. Also, there is an example of play with exactly this situation (player, who being stolen from, unsuccessfully tries to defend and is out of the game) and it explicitly says that captain still gets 2 coins.